# How to find max element in an unknown type array in c (using pointers to functions)

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, function, pointers

I'm trying to write a generic function, that gets an array of any type (`int`, `float`, `string`) and returns it's maximum element (if it's an array of strings - then lexicography). I managed to compile it, but when I run it, I get `segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *maxElement(void **arr, int size, int(*comp)(void*, void*)) {
    int i = 0;
    void *max = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (comp(arr[i], arr[i + 1])) {
            max = (void*)arr[i];        
        } else
            max = (void*)arr[i + 1];
    }
    return (void*)max;
}

int compareInt(void *a, void *b) {
    int *temp_a = (int*)a, *temp_b = (int*)b;

    if (*temp_a > *temp_b)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    int *result = 0;
    int array[4] = { 1, 3, 7, 0 };
    float array_f[4] = { 1.23, 6.57, 9.89, 11.56 };
    float result_f = 0;
    char string[5][6] = { "jess", "ron", "tom", "mia", "alex" };
    char answer[6];

    result = (int*)maxElement((void*)array, 4, &compareInt);
    printf("result: %d\n", *result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't know the type, you need to specify the size of the type (see [`qsort()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/qsort.html) for an example interface).  GCC notwithstanding, standard C does not allow you to do pointer arithmetic on `void *` because the size of the object pointed at is unknown.  You need to convert to a `char *`, do arithmetic based on index and element size, and then pass that to the comparison function.

Comment: your main problem that you're expecting array of pointers (`void **`), but you're passing array of integers (`int*`) you need to pass `int**`

Comment: Not yet mentioned is that `arr[i + 1];` breaks the array limit in the final loop iteration.

Comment: @IlyaBursov no, that's not proper either, `int**` is not compatible with `void**`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala afair standard allows you to convert `int*` into `void*` and then back without loosing anything

Comment: Yes, but they're not compatible in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is, that different types have a different sizes and so the memory offset of an array element depends on the index of the element and the type of the element. This means if you want to access an element of an array you have to know its type.

In your code you know the type of the array when you call `maxElement` and in the function which compares the elements, but not in the function `maxElement` itself. So you have to do the access to the array element in your compare function.

```
void *compareInt(void *a, void *b, int i) {
    int *temp_a = (int*)a;
    int *temp_b = ((int*)b) + i;
    return (temp_a > temp_b) ? a : (void*)temp_b;
}

void *maxElement(void *arr, int size, void*(*comp)(void*, void*, int)) {
    int i;
    void *max = arr;
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        max = comp( max, arr, i );
    }
    return max;
}
```

A similar solution, which does not require `sizeof` and not any additional parameter, would look like this:

```
int compareInt(void **a, void **b) {
    int *temp_a = (int*)(*a);
    int *temp_b = (int*)(*b);
    temp_b ++;
    *b = (void*)temp_b;
    *a = (*temp_a > *temp_b) ? temp_a : temp_b; 
    return *a != *b;
}

void *maxElement(void *arr, int size, int(*comp)(void**, void**)) {
    int i;
    void *max = arr;
    void *cur = arr;
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        comp( &max, &cur );
    }
    return max;
}
```

This might not be the best solution, but the other solution with the additional type size parameter in the `maxElement` function is pointed at almost perfectly in the other answers to this question.
I only wanted to show that one can solve the problem synonymous in the comparative functions.

Comment: wow, thank you so much  for the detailed answer. I managed to do it without the sizeof, but still, great solution.

Answer (score 5):

You are on the right track. Here are some pieces that were missing from your code:

- The array argument should have type `void*`, not `void**`.
- The function `maxElement` should take the number of elements **and** the size of an element, like `qsort()`.
- The `maxElement` function has flaws: it does not find the maximum and accesses an element past the end of the array.

These are optional, but recommended changes:

- The array argument should be const qualified as you are not modifying it.
- You should return the element index to avoid unnecessary casts, and all index and size variables should have type `size_t`.
- For consistency with `qsort` and `bsearch`, the comparison function should take `const void*` arguments and return `0` for elements that compare equal, a negative value if the first argument is *less* than the second and a non-zero positive value otherwise.

Here is the corresponding code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t maxElement(const void *arr, size_t count, size_t size,
                  int(*comp)(const void*, const void*)) {
    size_t i, res = 0;
    const unsigned char *p1 = arr;
    const unsigned char *p2 = p1 + size;

    for (i = 1; i < count; i++, p2 += size) {
        if (comp(p1, p2) < 0) {
            p1 = p2;
            res = i;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int compareInt(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    const int *i1 = p1, *i2 = p2;
    return (*i1 > *i2) - (*i1 < *i2);
}

int compareFloat(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    const float *f1 = p1, *f2 = p2;
    return (*f1 > *f2) - (*f1 < *f2);
}

int compareChars(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    const char *s1 = p1, *s2 = p2;
    return strcmp(s1, s2);
}

int compareString(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    const char * const *s1 = p1;
    const char * const *s2 = p2;
    return strcmp(*s1, *s2);
}

int main(void) {
    size_t result;
    int array[4] = { 1, 3, 7, 0 };
    float array_f[4] = { 1.23, 6.57, 9.89, 11.56 };
    char array_s[5][6] = { "jess", "ron", "tom", "mia", "alex" };
    const char *array_str[5] = { "jess", "ron", "tom", "mia", "alex" };

    result = maxElement(array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array),
                        sizeof(*array), compareInt);
    printf("int result: %d\n", array[result]);

    result = maxElement(array_f, sizeof(array_f) / sizeof(*array_f),
                        sizeof(*array_f), compareFloat);
    printf("float result: %f\n", array_f[result]);

    result = maxElement(array_s, sizeof(array_s) / sizeof(*array_s),
                        sizeof(*array_s), compareChars);
    printf("string result: %s\n", array_s[result]);

    result = maxElement(array_str, sizeof(array_str) / sizeof(*array_str),
                        sizeof(*array_str), compareString);
    printf("string result: %s\n", array_str[result]);

    return 0;
}
```

Note the difference between `array_s`, an array of fixed length character arrays and `array_str`, an array of string pointers.  They require different comparison functions.

Comment: @IlyaBursov: But then the data would have to be different — the set-up in main for integers would need to be: `int *data[] = { &array[0], &array[1], &array[2], &array[3] };` so that there is an array of `void *` pointing to the values.  And there'd be other consequential changes too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler exactly

Comment: @IlyaBursov: The interface to the maximum function doesn't match the standard (`qsort()` _is_ the standard in several senses of the term), and it makes life unnecessarily complicated.  So, the interface to `maxElement` needs more work.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler right, but OP decided to use `void**` and it is possible to use it here, so no need to pass additional argument

Comment: @IlyaBursov: I don't think the OP meant for the API to use `void **`, the way she calls the function indicates her intent, the `void**` is a mistake, and the size of each element must be passed along with the number of elements.  What you are proposing is a function that would take an array of pointer to objects: such an API is cumbersome to use for simple types and is not portable as the standard does not guarantee that `sizeof(void*) == sizeof(int*)` for example.

Comment: @chqrlie I actually suppose OP meant `void**` to compare strings, anyway we can only speculate

Comment: @IlyaBursov: that's a possibility, but in the examples in `main()`, he defines an array of arrays of `char`, not an array of `char *`.

Comment: @IlyaBursov: that's a possibility, but in the examples in `main()`, she defines an array of arrays of `char`, not an array of `char *`.

Comment: As i answered Rabbid76, I managed to do it without the sizeof, but thank you very much for your detailed solution!

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in a comment and [chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie) noted in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45152784/), there are a number of problems with the original code.  In particular, like the [`qsort()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/qsort.html) function, you need to pass the size of each element in the array to the function — and you should pass an array of values, not of pointers to values (see comments by [Ilya Bursov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864275/ilya-bursov) and responses by me amongst others).  Also, GCC notwithstanding, standard C does not allow you to do pointer arithmetic on `void *` because the size of the object pointed at is unknown. You need to convert to a `char *`, do arithmetic based on index and element size, and then pass that to the comparison function.

The generic function needed some work to compare the current maximum with new entries (and mercifully the test data needed to return the last value from one of the arrays; I had an off-by-one error that the tests spotted).

The comparators are rather unorthodox — they're not the same as the ones used by `qsort()` because they only return 0 or 1.  It would be better to modify them to return a negative value if the first argument compares smaller than the second, a positive value if the first argument compares larger than the second, and zero if the arguments compare equal.  The code in `maxElements()` will work correctly with either type of comparator, but you'd be able to sort with the same comparators if they match the 'standard' interface used by `qsort()`.

Making those changes, and some others, leads to code along the lines of:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void printStr(char **data, size_t num);
static void printDbl(double *data, size_t num);
static void printInt(int *data, size_t num);

int compareInt(const void *a, const void *b);
int compareDbl(const void *a, const void *b);
int compareStr(const void *a, const void *b);
void *maxElement(void *arr, size_t number, size_t size, int (*comp)(const void *, const void *));

void *maxElement(void *arr, size_t number, size_t size, int (*comp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    char *base = arr;
    void *max = base;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < number; i++)
    {
        if (comp(&base[i * size], max) > 0)
            max = &base[i * size];
    }

    return max;
}

int compareInt(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    int i1 = *(int *)a;
    int i2 = *(int *)b;

    return(i1 > i2);
}

int compareDbl(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    double d1 = *(double *)a;
    double d2 = *(double *)b;

    return(d1 > d2);
}

int compareStr(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    char *s1 = *(char **)a;
    char *s2 = *(char **)b;

    int rc = 0;
    if (strcmp(s1, s2) > 0)
        rc = 1;
    return rc;
}

int main(void)
{
    int     i_array[4] = { 11, 3, 7, 0 };
    double  d_array[4] = { 1.23, 6.57, 9.89, 11.56 };
    char   *s_array[5] = { "jess", "ron", "tom", "mia", "alex" };

    printInt(i_array, 4);
    int i_max = *(int *)maxElement(i_array, 4, sizeof(int), &compareInt);
    printDbl(d_array, 4);
    double d_max = *(double *)maxElement(d_array, 4, sizeof(double), &compareDbl);
    printStr(s_array, 5);
    char *s_max = *(char **)maxElement(s_array, 5, sizeof(char *), &compareStr);
    printf("Max integer: %d\n", i_max);
    printf("Max double:  %.2f\n", d_max);
    printf("Max string:  [%s]\n", s_max);
    return 0;
}

static void printStr(char **data, size_t num)
{
    const char *pad = "Strings:";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %s", pad, data[i]);
        pad = ",";
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

static void printDbl(double *data, size_t num)
{
    const char *pad = "Doubles:";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %.2f", pad, data[i]);
        pad = ",";
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

static void printInt(int *data, size_t num)
{
    const char *pad = "Integers:";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %d", pad, data[i]);
        pad = ",";
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Note that instead of a 2D array of `char`, I've opted to use a 1D array of `char *`.  You can write the code to handle the 2D array; it is less commonly necessary in practice.

Sample output:

```
Integers: 11, 3, 7, 0
Doubles: 1.23, 6.57, 9.89, 11.56
Strings: jess, ron, tom, mia, alex
Max integer: 11
Max double:  11.56
Max string:  [tom]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just take as a base the declaration of the standard C function `bsearch` ignoring its first parameter `key`.

```
void *bsearch(const void *key, const void *base,
              size_t nmemb, size_t size,
              int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

So the function `maxElement` can look the following

```
void * maxElement( const void *base, 
                   size_t nmemb, 
                   size_t size, 
                   int comp( const void *, const void * ) ) 
{
    const void *max = base;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < nmemb; i++ )
    {
        if ( comp( max, ( const char * )base + i * size  ) < 0 )
        {
            max = ( const char * )base + i * size;
        }
    }

    return ( void * )max;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void * maxElement( const void *base, 
                   size_t nmemb, 
                   size_t size, 
                   int comp( const void *, const void * ) ) 
{
    const void *max = base;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < nmemb; i++ )
    {
        if ( comp( max, ( const char * )base + i * size  ) < 0 )
        {
            max = ( const char * )base + i * size;
        }
    }

    return ( void * )max;
}

int compareInt( const void *a, const void *b ) 
{
    int lhs = *( const int * )a;
    int rhs = *( const int * )b;

    return ( rhs < lhs ) - ( lhs < rhs );
}

int compareFloat( const void *a, const void *b ) 
{
    float lhs = *( const float * )a;
    float rhs = *( const float * )b;

    return ( rhs < lhs ) - ( lhs < rhs );
}

int compareString( const void *a, const void *b ) 
{
    return strcmp( a, b );
}

int main( void ) 
{
    int array[4] = { 1, 3, 7, 0 };
    float array_f[4] = { 1.23, 6.57, 9.89, 11.56 };
    char string[5][6] = { "jess", "ron", "tom", "mia", "alex" };

    printf( "%d\n", *( int * )maxElement( array, 4, sizeof( int ), compareInt ) );
    printf( "%f\n", *( float * )maxElement( array_f, 4, sizeof( float ), compareFloat ) );
    printf( "%s\n", ( char * )maxElement( string, 5, sizeof( char[6] ), compareString  ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
7
11.560000
tom
```

Take into account that according to the convention adopted in the C Standard the comparison function shall return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero.